# Upload Image to Dropbox with URL

Tags: c#, .net, url, dropbox

```
DropboxClient dbx =  new DropboxClient("my_Key");

var folder = "/Apps/Images";

var file = $"fileName.jpg";

var fileToUpload = @"C:\Users\LENOVO\Test\Test\test.jpg";

using (var mem = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload)))
{

  var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(folder + "/" + file,
      WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
      body: mem);

     Console.WriteLine("Saved {0}/{1} rev {2}", folder, file, updated.Rev);
 }
```

i want to upload Image to Dropbox. This code is worked but i want fileToUpload to be is a web URL because images is a Web Server. i know i can download every Images step by step. But this is a loss of performance. If i write a WebUrl in the fileToUpload. i see the exception. For Example:
`fileToUpload = "https:\upload.wikimedia.org\wikipedia\commons\5\51\Small_Red_Rose.JPG`"

The Exception:

> C:\Users\LENOVO************\bin\Debug\net6.0\https:\upload.wikimedia.org\wikipedia\commons\5\51\Small_Red_Rose.JPG
>
> *** - is a local folder name

i want to upload image to dropbox from Web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `UploadAsync` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/gh-pages/obj/api/Dropbox.Api.Files.Routes.FilesUserRoutes.html#Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_UploadAsync_System_String_Dropbox_Api_Files_WriteMode_System_Boolean_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__System_Boolean_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Dropbox_Api_FileProperties_PropertyGroup__System_Boolean_System_String_System_IO_Stream_) requires that you supply the data of the file to upload directly, as you are doing in your example by retrieving the file data from the local filesystem using `File.ReadAllBytes`.

If you want to upload a file to Dropbox directly from a URL without downloading it to your local filesystem first, you should instead use [the `SaveUrlAsync` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/gh-pages/obj/api/Dropbox.Api.Files.Routes.FilesUserRoutes.html#Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_SaveUrlAsync_System_String_System_String_).